What porn movie used the theme from The Day the Earth Stood Still as incidental music?
A very long time ago, in the early 2000s Brazil, I was late-night surfing channels and suddenly recognized Bernard Herrmann’s theme.
It was, however, in one of the adult programming channels, on a time we didn’t have an on-screen guide. I didn’t bother to stay to discover which movie it was, but it seemed to be something from the 60s or 70s, with hippie aesthetics and a 16mm film feel.
Any idea what this movie actually was?

While questions about adult movies are on-topic here, this Meta question suggests that adult movie ID questions are off-topic.

I'm guessing the use was unlicensed. Good luck.

I’m voting to close this question because questions about identifying pornographic films are considered off-topic (see here).

This question is about porn and might be off topic, but I found an enter link description hereinteresting comment for the film Hitler’s Harlot (1973) on IMDB; bold emphasis is mine:

“I  detected snatches of: Melanie's ‘Look What They’ve Done to My Song Ma,’ some John Barry musical cues from ‘Thunderball,’ some Miklos Rozsa noir themes, Bobby Vinton’s ‘I Love How You Love Me,’ Nino Rota’s theme from ‘The Godfather,’ Hal David & Burt Bacharach’s ‘Trains and Boats and Planes,’ Gilbert O’Sullivan's ‘Alone Again Naturally,’ Larry Collins & Alex Harvey's Tanya Tucker hit ‘Delta Dawn,’ the Four Seasons’ ‘Candy Girl,’ Max Steiner’s ‘Gone With the Wind’ love theme and even a vamp from the Doors’ own version of ‘Light My Fire.’ Most of the ‘suspense’ music is from Bernard Herrmann’s ‘The Day the Earth Stood Still’ score, where Gort is finally unfrozen and making his moves. As die-hard porn fans are well-aware, these pirate efforts are never complete without stealing from Bernard Herrmann. Only surprise here was Ennio Morricone getting left out.”

So the film might be Hitler’s Harlot or it could have been any numerous porn films that stole (aka: “borrowed”) Bernard Herrmann’s work as well as the work of others.
